# GLSL Shader: FFT-Data as Circle Radius

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, shader

Im trying to crate a shader, that converts fft-data (passed as a texture) to a bar graphic and then to on a circle in the center of the screen. Here is a image of what im trying to achieve: [link to image](http://postimg.org/image/uwc34jxxz/)

i experimentet a bit with shader toy and came along wit this shader: [link to shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XlsSD2)

with all the complex shaders i saw on shadertoy, it thought this should be doable with maths somehow.

can anybody here give me a hint how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It’s very doable — you just have to think about the ranges you’re sampling in. In your Shadertoy example, you have the following:

```
float r = length(uv);
float t = atan(uv.y, uv.x);

fragColor = vec4(texture2D(iChannel0, vec2(r, 0.1)));
```

So `r` is going to vary roughly from 0…1 (extending past 1 in the corners), and `t`—the angle of the `uv` vector—is going to vary from 0…2π.

Currently, you’re sampling your texture at `(r, 0.1)`—in other words, every pixel of your output will come from the V position 10% down your source texture and varying across it. The angle you’re calculating for `t` isn’t being used at all. What you want is for changes in the angle (`t`) to move across your texture in the U direction, and for changes in the distance-from-center (`r`) to move across the texture in the V direction. In other words, this:

```
float r = length(uv);
float t = atan(uv.y, uv.x) / 6.283; // normalize it to a [0,1] range - 6.283 = 2*pi

fragColor = vec4(texture2D(iChannel0, vec2(t, r)));
```

For the source texture you provided above, you may find your image appearing “inside out”, in which case you can subtract `r` from 1.0 to flip it.

Comment: thx 4 the hint… i really have a bad math background ;-)… problem at the shadertoy fft-texture is, that it is a 512x2px Texture, where the first row is the fft values and the second is the wave-values. i will have to limit the r value somehow, but i will get that by my own hopefully…